# Why is my binary filled with paths, empty data and what is all of this?

Tags: c, visual-c++, executable

I recently tried to create the absolutely minimum sized binary in C with VC++.

To accomplish this I removed the C runtime library support in the settings and used this instead of the regular old main with the CRT setup that comes before it.

This is my source file:

```
int WinMainCRTStartup() {
return 0;
}
```

I also went around and removed anything that I could find that injected anything inside the outputted binary. There were a few things that I didn't understand why they were there.

This is the output:

*MZ.....................
@......................
.......................
!..L.!This program cann
t be run in DOS mode...
$.............d...d...d
..l...d...f...d.Rich..d
.......................
PE..L......X.........."
.......................
. ....@................
.........0............@
.......................
.......................
.......................
. ..p..................
.......................
.......................
.........text..........
.................... ..
.rdata....... .........
............@..@.......
.......................
.......................
.......................
.......................
.......................
.......................
.......................
.......................
.......................
.......................
.......................
.......................
.......................
.......................
.......................
.......................
.......................
.......................
.......................
.......................
................3......
.......................
.......................
.......................
.......................
.......................
.......................
.......................
.......................
.......................
.......................
.......................
.......................
.......................
.......................
.......................
.......................
.......................
.......................
.......................
.......................
.......................
.......X........Q...p .
p..........X...........
. .............X.......
@.... .............X...
................RSDS..
?..N............C:\Users\vlind\Desktop\minimumexe\Release\minimumexe.pd
.......................
GCTL.........text$mn...
. ..p....rdata..p .....
.rdata$zzzdbg..........
.......................
.......................
.......................
.......................
.......................
.......................
.......................
.......................
.......................
........*

I'm really interested in knowing what's exactly inside this executable and why. And what is the purpose of each part. What is .rdata for example? Why is there a path to a .pd file?...

I'll dump the linker flags and compiler flags as well if anyone happens to need them to answer the question.

**Compiler:**

> /GS- /TC /GL /analyze- /W4 /Gy /Zc:wchar_t /Zi /Gm- /O2 /Ob2
>   /Fd"Release\vc140.pdb" /Zc:inline /fp:fast /D "_MBCS"
>   /errorReport:prompt /WX- /Zc:forScope /Gd /Oy- /Oi /MD /Fa"Release\"
>   /nologo /Fo"Release\" /C /Fp"Release\minimumexe.pch"

**Linker:**

> /OUT:"C:\Users\vlind\Desktop\minimumexe\Release\minimumexe.exe"
>   /MANIFEST:NO /LTCG:incremental /NXCOMPAT /HEAP:"0"",0"
>   /PDB:"C:\Users\vlind\Desktop\minimumexe\Release\minimumexe.pdb"
>   /DYNAMICBASE "kernel32.lib" "user32.lib" "gdi32.lib" "winspool.lib"
>   "comdlg32.lib" "advapi32.lib" "shell32.lib" "ole32.lib" "oleaut32.lib"
>   "uuid.lib" "odbc32.lib" "odbccp32.lib" /LARGEADDRESSAWARE /DEBUG
>   /LTCG:STATUS /MACHINE:X86 /WINMD:NO /OPT:REF /SAFESEH:NO
>   /PGD:"C:\Users\vlind\Desktop\minimumexe\Release\minimumexe.pgd"
>   /SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS /MANIFESTUAC:NO /OPT:ICF /ERRORREPORT:PROMPT
>   /CLRUNMANAGEDCODECHECK:NO /NOLOGO /VERBOSE /NODEFAULTLIB /TLBID:1

Comment: Read [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms809762.aspx) *Inside a PE32 Executable*.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How is code stored in the EXE format?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14630852/how-is-code-stored-in-the-exe-format)

Comment: For starters, try getting rid of your `/Zi` and `/DEBUG` flags. Those generate debug info, which you're sticking in some PDB/PGD, which it looks like the path to those files are being stored in your .exe.

Comment: Did you try to use `strip.exe` a MinGW tool to reduce the size of your exe ?